# Query different paginated entities using JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, pagination

I have table Folders and Files. Folders and Files are mapped to appropriate entities Folder and File.

I need to make a paginated request to retrieve folders and files as separate entities. As a result it should look like a json:

```
   {
      folders: [...],
      files: [...],
   }
```

Moreover folders entities should come always first. E.g. if we have total 10 folders and 10 files and request is
`...?pageNumber=1&itemsPerPage=15`
the result should be:

```
   {
      folders: [...], // 10 folders
      files: [...] // 5 files
   }
```

Folder and File have common fields except Folder have field 'parentFolderKey' and File entity don't. Also File entity have field 'folderKey', but Folder don't.

If it would be just one entity it will be ok but how to make a paginated query to build such response with combined entities which have different fields (parentFolderKey, folderKey)? I'm also using JPA repositories and Spring. What can you suggest?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? In that case I could offer a specific solution (different from the one of crizzis below).

Comment: I'm trying to union tables and to query as a separate paginated entity using Pagable object. But if you share your solution with using hibernate it will be also interesting for me

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious answer would be to make them 'one entity' by tying `Folder` and `File` with an inheritance hierarchy. Perhaps both could inherit from something like a `FileSystemEntry`?

You could then query `FileSystemEntry` and `ORDER BY` the discriminator column to get `Folder`s on top. Splitting the list into `files` and `folders` is simply a matter of finding the first `File` in the result.

Answer (score 1):

If I would be able to define the table structure myself, I would go with the inheritance approach. As `File` and `Folder` share many properties, this is the most obvious way.

But if there is already a table structure, I would use a `@Subselect` in Hibernate in combination with a `UNION`:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("SELECT concat('folder.', id) fid, parentFolderKey parentFolder_Id, ... FROM Folder"
         + " UNION SELECT concat('file.', id) fid, folderKey parentFolder_Id, ... FROM File")
@Synchronize({ "Folder", "File" })
public FolderOrFile {
  
  @Id
  private String fid;

  @ManyToOne
  private Folder parentFolder;

  ... Common properties of files and folders

  public boolean isFile() { return fid.startsWith("file."); }

}
```

(The `@Synchronize` annotation is for ensuring that the cache for `FolderOrFile` is cleared, when a `Folder` or `File` entity is changed.)

You can now create a query for that entity even with paging.